# Why local notifications are not generated?

Tags: xcode

Using Xcode and objective C, all attempts to receive a notification failed.
This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)schedule:(id)sender  {
        UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
        content.title = @"Hello";
        content.body = @"Hello boys!";
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

        UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
           completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (granted) NSLog(@"granted");
            else NSLog(@"NOT granted %@",error);
        }];

        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
        triggerWithTimeInterval:15 repeats: NO];

        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"rid" content:content trigger:trigger];

        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"success");
            }
        }]; 
}
```

What I get are the Logs (granted, success) but no notification received; it should be generated after 15 sec.

Comment: How do you know no notification was received? If your app is frontmost when a notification arrives, by default nothing happens, so maybe that's the situation. Did you remember to background the app right after requesting the notification? You've only got 15 seconds so you have to move fast!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, trouble resolved. I did not realise that app must be in background to generate notifications.